# How to get previous month last Monday date in mule?

Tags: mule, dataweave

How to get previous month last Monday date in mule?

How could I get previous month last Monday based on payload?

Comment: Could you please describe the payload? Is a date in the payload and you need the last monday of the previous month before the date in the payload?

Answer (score 1):

The following [DataWeave 1.0](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-reference-documentation) snippet should do the work:

```
%dw 1.0
// %var payload = |2018-01-01|
%function getLastDayOfLastMonth(date)(date - "P$(date.day)D" )
%function getWeekday(date)(date.dayOfWeek)
%function getWeekdayOfLastDayOfPreviousMonth(date)(getWeekday(getLastDayOfLastMonth(date)))
%output application/json
---
{
   inputPayload : payload as :string {format : "yyyy-MM-dd"},
   periodAsString: |P04D| as :string,
   period: ("P$(payload.day)D") as :period,
   lastDayOfPreviousMonth: getLastDayOfLastMonth(payload),
   weekDayOfTheLastDayOfThePreviousMonth: getWeekdayOfLastDayOfPreviousMonth(payload),
   lastMondayOfPreviousMonth: getLastDayOfLastMonth(payload) - "P$(getWeekdayOfLastDayOfPreviousMonth(payload) - 1)D",
   lastSundayOfPreviousMonth: getLastDayOfLastMonth(payload) - "P$(getWeekdayOfLastDayOfPreviousMonth(payload))D"
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "inputPayload": "2018-01-01",
  "periodAsString": "P4D",
  "period": "P1D",
  "lastDayOfPreviousMonth": "2017-12-31",
  "weekDayOfTheLastDayOfThePreviousMonth": 7,
  "lastMondayOfPreviousMonth": "2017-12-25",
  "lastSundayOfPreviousMonth": "2017-12-24"
}
```

I have added some further fields to the Output to make it easier to understand, what happens. What you actually need is the "lastMondayOfPreviousMonth" value of the output.

Please note:

- You can create [periods](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-reference-documentation#adding-a-period-of-time) from strings: `"P1D"` or `"P${payload.day}D"`. See also: [String interpolation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-reference-documentation#string-interpolation).
- using this you can easily get the last day of the previous month for any given date you want to: `date - "P$(date.day)D"`
- From the last day of the previous month you can easily calculate any previous day. You just have to decrement it by the correct number of days.
- This DW snippet uses the first-day-of-the-week. This can be different for different locale Settings.

Comment: awesome answer!

Answer (score -1):

In DataWeave:

```
{ currentdateTime: (now as :localdatetime {format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"})as :string {format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}, beforedate: ((currentdateTime) - |P1D|)as :string {format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"} }
```

Comment: This DataWeave snippet won't solve the problem. This gets only the current date and the date for yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way is to use [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library for this and similar use cases. Here are the examples:

**With Mule 3.x and DataWeave 1.0**

**Step 1:** Include joda-time dependency in your project pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step 2:** Create a java class and a static function to get last Monday of the previous month. You can add more methods in this class based on the requirements.

```
package com.mycompany;

import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class DateFunction {

public static Date getLastMondayOfPreviousMonth() {
    return new LocalDate().minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue()
            .toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
    }

}
```

**Step 3:** Create a global function in mule xml file

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
    <expression-language>
        <import class="com.mycompany.DateFunction"/>
        <global-functions>
            def getLastMondayOfPreviousMonth() {
                return com.mycompany.DateFunction.getLastMondayOfPreviousMonth();          
            }
        </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

**Step 4:** Invoke this global function in DataWeave

```
<dw:transform-message>
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
        %output application/json
        ---
        {
            lastMondayOfPreviousMonth: getLastMondayOfPreviousMonth()
        }
    ]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

**With Mule 4.x and DataWeave 2.0**

**Step 1:** Include joda-time dependency in your project pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step 2:** Create a java class and a static function to get last Monday of the previous month. You can add more methods in this class based on the requirements.

```
package com.mycompany;

import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class DateFunction {

public static Date getLastMondayOfPreviousMonth() {
    return new LocalDate().minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue()
            .toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
    }

}
```

**Step 3:** Invoke this java static method in DataWeave (no need to create global function in this case)

```
<ee:transform>
    <ee:message>
        <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
            import java!com::mycompany::DateFunction
            output application/json
            ---
            {
                lastMondayOfPreviousMonth: DateFunction::getLastMondayOfPreviousMonth()
            }
        ]]></ee:set-payload>
    </ee:message>
</ee:transform>
```